# Spring Integration - Aggregating Priority Channel

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

I used Aggregator in spring integration and saw also that there is PriorityChannel. Is there possibility to use two of these somehow to achieve following requirements:

1. Messages are received from RabbitMQ and stored in spring component that has aggregator
2. Aggregator is doing aggregation but at a same time it prioritizes messages for release based on some complex sorting algorithm.
3. As the time passes by, message priorities inside queue can change, and we need to be able to re-schedule priorities at some point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PriorityChannel won't help with that, but you can do whatever you want in a custom `ReleaseStrategy`...

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ReleaseStrategy {

    boolean canRelease(MessageGroup group);

}
```

Comment: How is this method getting called? Is there some scheduler or? Since if it is calling on all messages I guess I would have a lot of wasted resources - at particular time I will have only 1 message that needs to be released, and then after that one next (which can be any of N messages I currently have in aggregator queue). Do you have any other suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: It is called when each message arrives; you can also set a `groupTimeout` and it will be called if no messages for the group arrive in that time. Your requirements are not entirely clear.